# My CSS is loading differently between development and production environments

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I can not quite figure out why my Rails app is displaying differently between production and development environments. I have confirmed that the same CSS files are being loaded between my local host and heroku app. There are several subtle differences. Containers aren't showing up the same size, text is showing up bigger than it should, weird things like that.

I am not sure what is causing the differences.

This is an example of inspecting the same container in the two different environments:

Local Host:

```
media="screen"
@media only screen and (max-width: 1300px)            localhost/
.container {                                          style.css?body=1:3319
width: 920px;
}
```

Heroku App:

```
media="screen"
@media only screen and (max-width: 1300px)             example-app.herokuapp.com/
.container {                                           style-e22efa48d….63ddab07.css:1
width: 920px;
}
```

They are both suppose to be loading style.css.scss

Totally lost here, not sure if it is an asset compilation deal, a media screen size issue, or maybe a SASS issue?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does your application.css look like? Are any CSS/SASS files being compiled lower down the chain in the application.css that might be overriding the CSS you've already written? Inspect the elements on Heroku and your local app  to see what styles are being applied and if anything is being overridden.

Comment: Ok here is the solution if anyone was wondering. In my app I had a certain CSS being compiled twice, this allowed for inexplicable changes in design and size. In conclusion, if you have font sizes showing up on your app, that are not anywhere in your CSS, look for an asset being compiled twice. -Cheers.