# Rails: Css appears to be different in dev and production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, styling

i have a standard rails 4/heroku setup. One thing is weird: The different elements of the page appear in different sizes for the local environment and for the production environment.

For example: Although the header-height is set to a specific pixel value it is different in height for the two environments.
Same with the width of the content: I set a max-width of 1260px - the width of the content is different for the two environments.

Everything appears bigger in production.

I found one related question, suggesting that the problem is due to assets which are compiled twice. Thats not the problem in my case...[My CSS is loading differently between development and production environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621428/my-css-is-loading-differently-between-development-and-production-environments)

Whats the reason for this behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, i solved it now. Its embarrassing, but maybe it helps someone else: I activated the browser zoom for localhost unintentionally. The reason why i didn't come up with this from the beginning was, that also search boxes and other elements appeared in a different style - even without any styles! Search boxes without browser zoom have rounded corners in chrome. With browser zoom of -1, search boxes appear rectangular. This is why i thought there are still styles applied, even i disabled all my stylesheets *facepalm*.

Maybe someone else can save some time with this hint.

Comment: Just checking in. 5 years later and I did this :facepalm:

Comment: I just did this as well. Had a senior dev sit down with me and we were both scratching our heads... :facepalm:

I even made another stackoverflow thread lol. Going to link this one there

Comment: I did same thing. You deserve extra vote.