# CSS seems to be different on deployment than in developement

Tags: css, node.js, webpack

I noticed recently that my css on localhost while i'm developing will look one way. Then when I deploy it to our QA environment with the same code base, it'll look different in the browser.

I did a side by side comparison and it just looks bigger in one vs the other. Can there be any reason why this may be happening?

Comment: are you using the same browser?

Comment: Yeah both are being viewed through chrome

Comment: Did you try doing a [reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or a [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) ?

Comment: I haven't tried a normalize but I do believe we have resets in place. The odd thing is that another developer on our team doesn't seem to be having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it lies here:
[Rails: Css appears to be different in dev and production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039102/rails-css-appears-to-be-different-in-dev-and-production)

It's quite embarrassing... but I had a different zoom on in localhost